# Shia Sources for first meet between Mahdi and Eesa

Tags: shiism, prophets

I need Shia narrations of Mahdi and eesa (Jesus) bin Maryam when they meet for the first time.

Kindly help me.May Allah reward you suitably.

Spoke to many Shia they didn't give any source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is reported that Jesus will say to al-Mahdi,

> “I was raised as a minister not as a commander.”
>
> [Sirat al-Mustaqim, 2, 220]

Hudhayfah reported that the Prophet (S) said,

> “Al-Mahdi will turn his face to Jesus when he descends as if water were dropping from his hair, and will say to him, ‘Go ahead and say the prayer.’ Jesus will say, ‘The prayer has been set up only for you.’ So, Jesus will pray behind a man who is among my sons.”
>
> [Sirat al-Mustaqim, 2, 257]

This is what will happen when Isa descends.

---

Source: [Al-Islam](https://www.al-islam.org/jesus-though-shiite-narrations-mahdi-muntazir-qaim/his-second-coming)(a Shia website)

Comment: Thanks, for your help, is that hadith(257) saheeh as per shia?

Comment: It is saheeh from both Shia and Sunni.

Comment: Here too, Mahdi is relinquishing lead of salat to eesa, Ali bin abu talib didn't act in such a way when he was the amir ul mumineen

Answer (score 0):

The Holy Prophet (PBUH) says: I swear by God, if there is one day left in the life of the world, God will prolong that day so that my son Mahdi will leave. He prays and that is when the rule of the Mahdi will spread in the east and west of the world. It is certain that the descent of Jesus (pbuh) and the offering of prayers to the Imamate of the Imam of the Age (pbuh) occur in the age of advent. That is, in practice, following the allegiance of Jesus Christ (pbuh) to Hazrat Mahdi (pbuh), the Jewish community and the Christian community comprehensively believe in the Imam of the Age (pbuh).

One of the important achievements of Imam Mahdi's (as) movement in the political arena is a kind of peace agreement with the international community that is formed following the allegiance of Jesus Christ (as) to him. This is a good opportunity for Christians and Jews to pledge allegiance to the Imam of the Age. Numerous narrators have quoted the Holy Prophet (PBUH) as saying: The Mahdi (AS), who is from the Ahl al-Bayt (AS), will go out and fill the earth with justice, just as Jesus (AS) descended and Imam Mahdi (as) follows.

Ref.: http://shabestan.ir/detail/News/936567